# InnoDB: Cannot open table from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists

Tags: mysql, windows, xampp

I am running Windows 10 with XAMPP and several dozen Drupal sites installed on localhost. Everything has been working fine for months.

This morning I performed a Windows restore from a restore point two days ago to get rid of an unwanted Windows update. After I did that, my MySQL stopped working. I tried deleting the file `ibdata1` (I now know that that was a bad idea), but when things got worse, I restored the initial `ibdata1` that I'd deleted. All the table data (`.frm` and `.ibd` files) is still in `C:\xampp\mysql\data`. Now MySQL will at least start, but all the tables are "gone"... I can load phpMyAdmin in the browser, and when I drop down the databases at left, all the tables show... but when I try to click on one, it tells me "table not found."

In `mysql_error.log` there are several errors like `InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/slave_master_info from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists.` There is a URL mentioned in the error message that supposedly tells you how to resolve this issue, but it is uninformative.

I don't *think* `ibdata1` is corrupted... and all the articles regarding recovering data are complicated to a degree that is *insanely* out of proportion to the problem. No one has a simple spelled-out solution. Am I Googling wrong? This has happened to me at least twice before, and each time the problem spontaneously resolved itself before I was able to start following the 10-hour-long procedures I found online. Not this time, unfortunately. Surely I'm missing something simple. I had hundreds and hundreds of tables in a few dozen databases, and it seems hopeless to try to find the schema for each one and manually plug it in, which is what most recovery articles seem to suggest.

Shouldn't the database just know how to read the `.frm` and `.ibd` files, and, you know... work? It *feels* like there's just one value out of place somewhere, and if I could just find it, everything would just "pop" back into place.

Comment: So as this sort of thing has happened before, you will of course have made sure that you have made regular backups of all these valuable resources (databases) **Right**?

Comment: Never knew how to do that. The issue is, all the data is right there... why can't it see it?

Comment: I cannot help thinking that after 2 near miss LOUD warnings you deserve to loose the lot, but lets start by you posting the relevant section i.e, the end of your `mysql error log` so we can see what errors MYSQL is reporting

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6621447/mysql.txt

Comment: You said you had many databases. Is it only one that is reporting these errors or all of them?

Comment: Only one is giving the errors... but all of them have all their tables missing in everything that tries to access them. Could it be that the database that is corrupted contains all the information about the rest of them?

Answer (score 2):

What did the work for us was this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html) (Restoring Orphan File-Per-Table ibd Files).

In brief, you do:

```
ALTER TABLE ..... DISCARD TABLESPACE;
```

For each affected table.
Then, for each affected table:

```
ALTER TABLE .... IMPORT TABLESPACE; SHOW WARNINGS;
```

You could do that on the same schema or create a new schema in other database and copy all *.ibd files. In this case:

> - Create the new schema with table definitions.
> - Do the discard tablespace for all tables.
> - Copy the new *.ibd files to the right folder of new schema.
> - Do de import tablespace for all tables.

**IMPORTANT!** It's better that the new schema has the same name as the old one.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/42932

My dbs was InnoDB, so there is a problem with id and when upgrading the macos, I got this. I will quote the main part:

> You must have:
>
> -ibdata1
>
> -ib_logfile0
>
> -ib_logfile1
>
> -.FRM files from your mysql_database folder
>
> -Fresh installation of MAMP / MAMP Pro that you are willing to destroy (if need be)
>
> 1. SSH into your web server (dev, production, no difference) and browse to your mysql folder (mine was at /var/lib/mysql for a Plesk
>      installation on Linux)
> 2. Compress the mysql folder
> 3. Download an archive of mysql folder which should contain all mySQL databases, whether MyISAM or innoDB (you can scp this file, or move
>      this to a downloadable directory, if need be)
> 4. Install MAMP (Mac, Apache, MySQL, PHP)
> 5. Browse to /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/
> 6. Backup /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql to a zip archive (just in case)
> 7. Copy in all folders and files included in the archive of the mysql folder from the production server (mt Plesk environment in my case)
>      EXCEPT DO NOT OVERWRITE:
>
>    -/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/mysql/
>
>    -/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/mysql_upgrade_info
>
>    -/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/performance_schema

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was restoring the backup (done by galera-arbitrator and xtrabackup. Using the first one we took state-snapshot and using the last one we backed up the physical data) for **Percona_XtraDB_Cluster**. So, after placing the backed up data to the dir `/var/lib/mysql` of the new mysql server, we did the following `select` query and got error.

```
$ mysql -uroot -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD -h<NEW_SERVER_HOST_NAME> -e 'show columns from <MY_DB>.<MY_TABLE>'
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1: Table 'playground.equipment' doesn't exist
```

And the server log was:

```
[Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table <MY_DB>/<MY_TABLE> from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how to resolve the issue.
```

We just restarted the container the new data. That's it

Comment: What do you mean "We just restarted the container the new data"? Restart the MySQL database? I've tried that. I have exactly the same issue - I've moved all (yes, *all*) the files (MySQL binaries and all the data) to another PC. I've updated the datadir location in my.ini. And I'm getting exactly the same error as the OP. All the frm and ibd files are there, MySQL just refuses to use them! (Windows, MySQL 5.7.25)

Comment: Actually the whole runtime setup was in the docker container. So restarting the container means everything inside the container runtime be restarted.

Comment: OK, in my case, although I'd copied all the files, a couple of them ended up in the wrong location... PICNIC... once I'd sorted that out, it started fine...:(

Answer (score -3):

Just rename slave_master_info.frm to slave_master_info.BAK and that's it. Restart the mysql service.